# Login in android using json post method

Tags: android, json, android-studio, authentication

Im working on an android application with a login page using a json web service(POST). When I try to login it crashes.

Here is my code:

```
login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = edit_email.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = edit_password.getText().toString().trim();
            call_api(email, password);
        }
});

private void call_api(final String email, final String password) {
     AsyncTask<String,String,String> sync=new AsyncTask<String, String,  String>() {
          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              super.onPreExecute();
              pd.setMessage("Please wait");
              pd.show();
          }

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

              HttpClient clent = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://steerapps.com/yardin/webservice.php?action=login?email="+email+"&password="+password);
              try {
                  HttpResponse respon = clent.execute(post);
                  result1 = EntityUtils.toString(respon.getEntity());

                  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result1);
                  String s = object.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
                  message = object.getJSONObject("response").getString("message");

                  Log.e("message", "" + message);
              }catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
              super.onPostExecute(s);
              pd.cancel();
              if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("You are login Successfully"))
              {
                  Intent it=new Intent(login_Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(it);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Login Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

              }else {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Login Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
              }
          }
      };
      sync.execute();
}
```

Comment: please clean up the question, it has several typos/formatting issues.

Comment: post you stack trace so we know what went wrong

Comment: @Tomer  what i post

Comment: You shouldn't use the name `object` for the variable. Rename it to `jsonObject` (I'm referring to the line `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result1);`)

Comment: @Vucko that shouldnt matter

Comment: Yeah, but only because it's lower case o, I'm just saying it's a bad practice. Could've mistakenly put upper case O, and caused himself world of trouble for nothing.

Comment: Post the logcat please dude..

Comment: Logcat
 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                at com.login.Login_Activity$6.onPostExecute(Login_Activity.java:297)
                                                                at com.login.Login_Activity$6.onPostExecute(Login_Activity.java:240)
                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)

Answer (score 0):

Return message instead of null, you are returning null to onPostExecute method by your doInBackground() method which will be accepted by "String s" argument and you are calling super.onPostExecute(s) so , the null argument is passing to that method so, just change this line

> return null

to

> return message

in your doInBackground Method :)

Answer (score 0):

Make `String s` global and then change

```
String s = object.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
message = object.getJSONObject("response").getString("message");
```

to

```
s = object.getString("message");
```